# UIView frame not updating after orientation change

Tags: ios, swift

How to detect orientation change after it happened using Swift 3?

I need to detect it after change to calculate frame size.

**EDIT**

I asked this question because I need to redraw view on orientation change like in this question: [Can't get background gradient to fill entire screen upon rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20925939/cant-get-background-gradient-to-fill-entire-screen-upon-rotation)

I don't know how to implement answer that is marked as a correct answer.

I tried another answer

```
self.backgroundImageView.layer.sublayers?.first?.frame = self.view.bounds
```

but it's not working.

In `viewDidLoad()` I have

```
let color1 =  UIColor(red: 225.0/255.0, green: 210.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
let color2 = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 125.0/255.0, blue: 77.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor

let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.colors = [color1, color2]
gradientLayer.locations = [ 0.0, 1.0]
gradientLayer.frame = self.view.bounds

self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
```

Comment: __A.__ you can be sure to create the proper view-hierarchy and try not to brake the notification chain which supported by iOS automatically; or __B.__ you can subscribe for `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` and listen to the orientation changes and update your custom view when it is necessary.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The above accepted answer returns frame size before transition.So your view is not updating..You need to get the frame size after the transition has been completed.

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void in

            let orient = UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation

            switch orient {

            case .portrait:

                print("Portrait")

            case .landscapeLeft,.landscapeRight :

                print("Landscape")

            default:

                print("Anything But Portrait")
            }

            }, completion: { (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void in
                //refresh view once rotation is completed not in will transition as it returns incorrect frame size.Refresh here           

        })
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    }
```

Comment: I tried a bunch of things but I couldn't find a solution which would have the updated view frames. The fact that the completion handler is executed after the view frames solves the problem and your answer is really helpful.

Comment: This is an awesome solution if you need the new (after rotation) frame size! Thank you so much. The only thing I noticed is that this delegate method is sometimes called twice. So in order to prevent refreshing the view twice unnecessarily I store the old orientation and only if new orientation is different I refresh the view. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 7):

Add this function and you´ll detect the orientation change:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        print("Landscape")
    } else if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait {
        print("Portrait")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works, but I have another problem because of which I asked this question in the first place. I updated my question. Could you check it out?

Comment: Try to `self.view.setNeedsLayout()` at the end of your `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 6):

To get orientation change callback you need to add this Notification

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.rotated), name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)
```

and you need to implement this method

```
func rotated() {
    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.current.orientation))
    {
        print("landscape")
    }

    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice.current.orientation))
    {
        print("Portrait")
    }
}
```

Comment: awesome! much better than `viewWillTransition`, it's like `viewDidTransition` (which isn't available)

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution, based on these requirements:

(1) My layout needed to change based on which dimension was larger, height or width. (Basically portrait or landscape, but in the future...?)

(2) My app is universal, so I could not consider size classes or any override related to them.

(3) My app also has a photo editing extension, so UIApplication was unavailable. (Also, orientations such as landscapeLeft and landscapeRight do not work in this type of extension.)

NOTE: I'm adding my structure for AutoLayout for completeness.

**UIViewController:**

```
var p = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
var l = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
var initialOrientation = true
var isInPortrait = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // set up all constraints, including common, portrait and landscape
    setUpConstraints()  
}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    if initialOrientation {
        initialOrientation = false
        if view.frame.width > view.frame.height {
            isInPortrait = false
        } else {
            isInPortrait = true
        }
        orientationChanged()
    } else {
        if view.orientationHasChanged(&isInPortrait) {
            orientationChanged()
        }
    }
}

func orientationChanged() {
    // this was split out because of other app-specific logic
    view.setOrientation(p, l)
}
```

**UIView:**

```
extension UIView {

    public func orientationHasChanged(_ isInPortrait:inout Bool) -> Bool {
        // always check against isInPortrait to reduce unnecessary AutoLayout changes!
        if self.frame.width > self.frame.height {
            if isInPortrait {
                isInPortrait = false
                return true
            }
        } else {
            if !isInPortrait {
                isInPortrait = true
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
    public func setOrientation(_ p:[NSLayoutConstraint], _ l:[NSLayoutConstraint]) {
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(l)
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(p)
        if self.bounds.width > self.bounds.height {
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(l)
        } else {
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(p)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    if UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation) {

        print("Landscape mode called")

        if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == .Pad {
            print("Landscape mode in ipad");

        }
        else
        {
            print("Landscape mode in Iphone ")

        }
    } else {
        print("Portrait mode called")
        if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == .Pad {

            print("Portrait mode called in ipad")
        }
        else
        {
            print("Portrait mode called in iphone")
        }
    }
}
override func willRotateToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: NSTimeInterval) {
    print("willRotateToInterfaceOrientation method called");
    //Here you can invalidateLayout()
}
```

Comment: This is not correct...Use viewWillTransition instead.

Comment: @Anish웃 it's working for me..you can just try this code

Comment: it works but viewWillTransition is only called when device rotates,but viewWillLayoutSubviews may call several times

Comment: @Anish웃 you are right but you can also invalid the layout and thanx for correcting me.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func willRotate(to toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: TimeInterval) {

    self.sliding.setNeedsDisplay()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this to get the updated value of traitCollection, use this instead

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    print("Trait collection changes")

}
```